# Why does FOR /F "skip=0" fail?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

In a standard windows batch file (.cmd) I want to do:

```
FOR /F "skip=0" %%G IN (filename.txt) DO ( ECHO %%G )
```

but I get `" was unexpected at this time.`

`"skip=1"` works fine (In my actual code `0` is a variable).

According to [ss64.com](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) the default is `skip=0`, but it seems not to work when explicitly set.

Am I doing it wrong? Or is there a workaround I can use?

**Edit:**

I have tried this on both Windows server 2003 and Windows 7.

The content of filename.txt could be:

```
something
stuff
unicorns
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It really doesn't like the `0`, causing the parser to expect more after it (You can also trip it when trying to use `09` which it tries parsing as octal, which fails).

I guess you need to create an environment variable holding the entire `skip=n` part or nothing and insert that into the argument list. Something like

```
if %N% GTR 0 (
  set SKIP="skip=%N%"
) else (
  set SKIP=
)
```

and then use

```
for /f %SKIP% %%G ...
```

(or without the quotes if you need to pass more options).

Comment: awesome. I corrected the code so the `set` commands are on their own lines. Otherwise the `SKIP` will be set to something unwanted. :)

Comment: @steenhulthin: May I ask what you mean?

Comment: @Andriy Of course. If you look in the history you will see that the code initially was in one line: `if %N% GTR 0 set SKIP="skip=%N%" else set SKIP=`, which would cause `%SKIP%` to be set to `"skip=%N%" else set SKIP=` if `%N%` is greater than 0.

Comment: @steenhulthin: Perfectly, thank you! Although I tend to use parantheses in one-liners to avoid that, somehow I couldn't recognise that bug immediately. Thanks again for reminding me that!

Answer (score 0):

I add a ""false"" first line to avoid the IF line(s) and keep the "skip" anytime :

```
::   liste des fichiers du repertoire et de ses sous-repertoires
echo ***   liste des fichiers du repertoire et de ses sous-repertoires >%FicListImg%
dir /s /b /a:-d %RepImg%\*.*  >> %FicListImg%
set compteurA=0
for /f %%a in (%FicListImg%) do set /a CompteurA+=1  
set /a CompteurA = %CompteurA%-1
set /a NbImg = %CompteurA%-1
@echo Repertoire Images : %RepImg%  (%NbImg% images)
```